# Wrong redirection : problem with vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

i want to access to http://admin.my-app.com

It is supposed to point on web/**backend.php**, but when i try to access via the URL, it redirects me to the *index.php* of my application.

I don't know what i've done wrong.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName admin.my-app.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/web
        DirectoryIndex backend.php
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/web>
                AllowOverride none
                allow from all
        </Directory>

         Alias /sf /var/www/myapp/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
          <Directory "/var/www/myapp/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
                 AllowOverride none
                 Allow from All
          </Directory>

        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

And it takes me to :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.my-app.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/web
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        <Directory /var/www/myapp/web>
                AllowOverride All
                allow from all
        </Directory>

         Alias /sf /var/www/myapp/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
          <Directory "/var/www/myapp/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
                 AllowOverride All
                 Allow from All
        </Directory>
        ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

and the .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-app.com
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-app.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the last `RewiteRule` in your `.htaccess` setting it to `index.php`?

Comment: I've disallowed appache to look for the .htaccess when accessing to admin.my-app.com by removing AllowOverride (or setting it to none)

Comment: Do you have vhost logs? Do you actually see it going to admin vhost?